# MongoDB: Find objects with field names starting with

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Query for a MongoDB: From a given collection (see example below) I need only objects listed that comprise fields, where the field name starts with "need_".

Example of a collection with three objects

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "need_some" : "A",
    "need_more" : 1,
    "website_id" : "123456789"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "need_more" : 2,
    "website_id" : "123456789"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "website_id" : "123456789"
}
```

Desired Output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "need_some" : "A",
    "need_more" : 1,
    "website_id" : "123456789"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "need_more" : 2,
    "website_id" : "123456789"
}
```

Query could look something like

```
db.getCollection('nameCollection').find({ "need_.*"  : { "$exists" : true }})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use below aggregation using [**`$objectToArray`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) in mongodb **3.4** and above

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "field": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$match": { "field.k": { "$regex": "need_" }}},
  { "$project": { "field": 0 }}
])
```

Will give you [**output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b67Zr4uGzh0)

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "need_more": 1,
    "need_some": "A",
    "website_id": "123456789"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "need_more": 2,
    "website_id": "123456789"
  }
]
```

Comment: Spitze, danke. Dauert ein Weilchen, hat aber sofort funktioniert. Danke!

Comment: *Spitze, danke. Dauert ein Weilchen, hat aber sofort funktioniert. Danke!* What does it mean?

Comment: Oh sorry! it means "Excellent. It takes a while, but it works. Thanks a lot"